# How to enable clang's module TS?

Tags: c++, module, clang, c++20

simple question. I'm using CMake and VSCode for a simple c++ project, and I'd like to use clang's module TS. I've tried both `-fmodules` and `fmodules-ts`, but both flags are unrecognized.

My CMakeLists.txt file:

```
add_executable(test
  test.cpp
)

set_target_properties(test
  PROPERTIES 
    CXX_STANDARD 20
)

target_compile_options(test 
  PRIVATE
    "-fmodules" # or "-fmodules-ts"
    "-Wall"
    "-Wextra"
    "-Wnon-virtual-dtor"
    "-Wnoexcept"
    "-Wconversion"
)
```

and, in the build directory's `compile-commands.json` file, the command used when compiling is this:

`/usr/bin/c++ -g -fmodules -Wall ... -std=gnu++2a -o <destination> -c  <my .cpp file>`.

When running `CXX=clang cmake ..` in my `build/` directory, the command is set as `/usr/bin/c++`, so I'm guessing it's an alias of some sort.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

For clarity, the error given is:

`c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-fmodules'; did you mean '-fmudflap'?`

Comment: Which clang version are you using?

Comment: Clang 8.0.0. my CMakeTools kit says `Using compilers: C = /usr/bin/clang-8`

Comment: Perhaps `/usr/bin/c++` is not clang? try running `/usr/bin/c++ --version` or just check where `/usr/bin/c++` (which is probably a symlink or some frontend) leads.

Comment: Oh my gosh `/usr/bin/c++ --version` outputs GCC 8.2.1. Well, guess that's my problem. No idea cmake won't correctly set it as clang.

Comment: @VTT I figured it out. Apparently `/usr/bin/c++` is considered to be whatever my system's default c++ compiler is, and was a symlink to g++. I changed it to clang and it compiles now.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. `/usr/bin/c++` is considered the default compiler on POSIX systems, and my OS is compliant with POSIX. `c++` was a symlink to the `g++` compiler, so I just updated the symlink to point to `/usr/bin/clang`. I suppose this is because my CMakeTools kit only had clang for C, and that cmake assumed the default `usr/bin/c++` is what I would want for C++.